# How to add automatically a video ending?

Tags: video, editing

Long story short, for internal trading videos updates i need to add a predone video cut to a lot of old videos. I need a way to not having to pass everyone one by one by premiere. Any software that could do that?

Comment: are you familiar with ffmpeg? You could write a batch-script using ffmpeg to concat the ending to any video automatically after running the script.

Comment: @Florian Claaßen Never used it and coding is not my expertise, to say the least

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your clips are the same format and dimensions:

Using FFmpeg, I think this would append the "ending.mp4" on to "file1.mp4" and save it as "output1.mp4":

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:file1.mp4|ending.mp4" -c copy output1.mp4
```

On a Mac, I would install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh), then run the [ffmpeg brew command](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ffmpeg) to install FFmpeg.

You can also do this using [Adobe Media Encoder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMwRwgqfSd4), but would take longer if you have many clips.

Answer (score -1):

Quicktime in Apple has a trim and drop edit function built into the player app.
You just copy your footage in the time line and drop it into the old footage in the right place. Pretty useful for a light edit.